# How to initialize a class variable with reference to another class variable in Python?

Tags: python

I'd like to initialize two class variables: the first one is a constant, the second one a list (or set, dict, etc) that is built based on the value of the first constant. An example of what I'd like to do, which doesn't work:

```
class ThisDoesntWork:
   SOME_CONST = "hello"
   SOME_OTHER_CONST = list(SOME_CONST + str(i) for i in range(4))
```

Results in:

```
NameError: name 'SOME_CONST' is not defined
```

As found in another answer, the following code works, as long as there is no list, dict, set:

```
class ThisWorks:
   SOME_CONST = "hello"
   SOME_OTHER_CONST = SOME_CONST + str(1)
```

It feels like I'm missing some core concept in how classes and namespaces work, which breaks the first example but not the second. What is it, and what is a good way to do this well?

Comment: This is an unfortunate quirk/wart that occurs because of the way comprehension-constructs create a function scope and the way that class namespaces are special-cased to not create an enclosing scope

Comment: Thank you for linking the other question, it has a great detailed answer! Sorry for the dup, could not find that one despite all the searching.

Comment: No worries, it's an obscure thing to search for.